# How to make type inference try deref coercion?

Tags: rust

I'm working on (yet another) [Advent of Code](https://adventofcode.com/) framework. Because the solutions to the puzzles should remain simple to write, the goal is to make the code below work *unmodified*:

```
/// Sometimes a string is easier to work with.
fn run1(_input: &str) {
}

/// Sometimes bytes are easier or faster.
fn run2(_input: &[u8]) {
}

fn main() {
    run1(&input());
    run2(&input());
}
```

Here, the `input` function loads input from a file. Hence, it must return an owned type, not a reference. This can either be `Vec<u8>` or `String`.

To that end, I've written the following `Input` trait:

```
/// Type of puzzle input that can be loaded: string or raw bytes.
trait Input {
    fn from_bytes(bytes: Vec<u8>) -> Self;
}

impl Input for String {
    fn from_bytes(bytes: Vec<u8>) -> Self {
        String::from_utf8(bytes).unwrap()
    }
}

impl Input for Vec<u8> {
    fn from_bytes(bytes: Vec<u8>) -> Self {
        bytes
    }
}
```

Now how do I define the `input()` function? The naive signature:

```
/// Imagine this loads some input from a file.
fn input<I: Input>() -> I {
    I::from_bytes(vec![])
}
```

This is fine until I try to call it. `run1` takes a `&str`, but `&input()` can at best be of type `&String`, leading to errors like this:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `str: Input` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:10:11
   |
10 |     run1(&input());
   |           ^^^^^ the trait `Input` is not implemented for `str`
   |
   = help: the trait `Input` is implemented for `String`
note: required by a bound in `input`
  --> src/main.rs:32:13
   |
32 | fn input<I: Input>() -> I {
   |             ^^^^^ required by this bound in `input`
```

`str` cannot be used as the return type of `input()`, because it's not `Sized`, so `impl Input for str` is out of the question. So the coercion from `String` to `str` has to happen outside the `input()` function.

What I want to express is that the return type can be coerced from `String` to `str`, but in such a way that type inference can still infer `I = String` when it sees that a `str` is required. I think the `Deref` trait comes into play here, but I haven't been able to figure out how to solve things with it.

Can this be made to work, or am I asking too much of the type system?

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a0c16c3bb914273eebbda9ab7966bdff)

Comment: Why not specify the type parameter, i.e. `run1(&input::<String>()); run2(&input::<Vec<u8>>());`? Or take owned `String` and `Vec<u8>`?

Comment: Why not specify the type parameter: because this needs to be written quickly, ain't nobody got time for that. Why not take owned values: because it's not idiomatic Rust.

Comment: I don't think you should care for idiomatic Rust in code for AOC that is use-and-throw-away.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman People don't all partake in AoC for the same reasons. Please allow me to decide for myself what I do and don't care for.

Comment: If you're ok with leaking memory, you can make it work like so: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=09400a109860fe45943c805a8fc07c3b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably make `Input` a `struct` and implement `AsRef<str>` and `AsRef<[u8]>` for it.
Then with a minor tweak from `&input()` to `input().as_ref()` we can do this:

(assuming you actually only want to call `run1` and `run2` in the same manner rather than having it exactly `run1(&input())`)

```rust
/// Sometimes a string is a useful input.
fn run1(_input: &str) {
}

/// Sometimes bytes are easier.
fn run2(_input: &[u8]) {
}

fn main() {
    run1(input().as_ref());
    run2(input().as_ref());
}

/// Type of puzzle input that can be loaded: string or raw bytes.
struct Input {
    bytes: Vec<u8>
}

impl AsRef<[u8]> for Input {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &[u8] {
        &self.bytes
    }
}

impl AsRef<str> for Input {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &str {
        std::str::from_utf8(&self.bytes)
    }
}

/// Imagine this loads some input from a file.
fn input() -> Input {
    Input {bytes: vec![]}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I can live with the `as_ref` call but it would be nicer if it wasn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the other side of the question; you can't get the desired behavior using [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#more-on-deref-coercion)-coercion.

`Deref` can be implemented for a type only once. Yes, the compiler can auto-dereference multiple times from a single `&`, but it only goes down a *chain* of implementations. This could theoretically work if `str` implemented `Deref<Target = [u8]>`, but alas it doesn't. So its not possible.